# Big Query Remote Function Limit

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-run

When trying to run multiple concurrent Big Query queries which use remote function, pretty fast I run into an error says:

> Exceeded rate limits: too many concurrent queries with remote functions for this project. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/troubleshoot-quotas

Looking in the [quotas and limit](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas) doc, I see that "Maximum number of concurrent queries that contain remote functions" set to 10 queries by default, which is pretty tight limit.

Is there a way to change this default and increase the quota? I've looked after this quota in Quotas & System Limits page in my project, but found nothing.
Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like it is a system limit, rather than a quota - and as such can't be increased: [GCP Quotas and Limits](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota/understand-limits). It might be worth deploying your function using Cloud Functions Gen 2, if you haven't already - as I believe they handle concurrency differently to Gen 1.

Comment: The quota is per running and thus billing project. The data can be in another project. By having two billing projects this limit can doubled.

Answer (score 1):

The error message `"Exceeded rate limits: too many concurrent queries with remote functions for this project"` indicates that your Google Cloud project has **exceeded the quota limit** for the maximum number of concurrent queries that contain remote functions in Google BigQuery.

In your case, it's because you are running multiple queries concurrently, and these queries involve remote functions in BigQuery. Remote functions are functions that are executed on external resources, such as User-Defined Functions (UDFs) or functions that call external services.

Also, the error message directs you to the BigQuery documentation for troubleshooting quotas. This documentation provides information on how to handle quota-related issues, including how to request quota increases if needed. It's a resource to help you understand why the error occurred and what steps you can take to resolve it.

To mitigate this error, you can either reduce the number of concurrent queries with remote functions or [request a quota increase](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quotas/view-manage#requesting_higher_quota) for the maximum number of concurrent queries with remote functions in your Google Cloud project, as explained in the documentation provided in the error message.